# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from' (NOT IN)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I’m trying to match different transactions but I’m not able to find why this is not working. The problem is with the last `FROM (c.ClientId from #amount1)`. I’ve tried to use temporary tables and CTE and even trying the full subquery directly. I’ve tried the `NOT EXISTS` as well but I’m interested in `NOT IN` so I want the `NULL` values.

```
SELECT * 
into #transactions
FROM #amount1
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM #amount2
UNION ALL
select  c.ClientId,
    c.ClientName,
    c.Date
    t.currency
from #clients c
LEFT JOIN transaction t ON c.ClientId = t.ClientID
WHERE c.ClientId NOT IN ( c.ClientId from #amount1)
AND c.ClientId NOT IN ( c.ClientId from #amount2)
```

Many thanks.

**UPDATE**: My error was that I was missing the SELECT:

```
 WHERE c.ClientId NOT IN ( SELECT ClientId from #amount1)
 AND c.ClientId NOT IN ( SELECT ClientId from #amount2)
```

I'm so sorry for this. I'm quite new and I have often errors like this but this time I didn't realise.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it shouldn't work because it doesn't make sense.

try something like this:

```
WHERE c.ClientId NOT IN ( select [clientid] from #amount1)
```

`[clientid]` is whatever the matching column is in `#amount1`

you'll have to do the same in the second `NOT IN` clause as well.

Comment: thanks for your help but that's not the problem. It gives me exactly the same error.

Comment: it's the same error. It's like I can't use the NOT IN in this query.

Comment: @Maria update your question to show the modified query which is getting the error. Show where you are defining `#amount1` and `#amount2`